# function mkdircd () {mkdir -p "$@" && eval cd "\"\$$#\""; }

Tags: linux, bash, shell

actually,I can't understand the end of this code:

```
function mkdircd () {
    mkdir -p "$@" && eval cd "\"\$$#\"";
}
```

eval is a command,but what the meaning of the end of symbol?
---> `cd "\"\$$#\""`

```
$mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar/
$cd /tmp/foo/bar
$pwd
/tmp/foo/bar
```

add this function into .bashrc

```
$mkdircd /tmp/foo/bar/
$pwd
/tmp/foo/bar/
```

Comment: Why not `mkdir -p "$@" && cd "$@";` ? I don't get it...

Comment: @devnull: No, `$#` expands first to the number of arguments, then when eval'ed the first dollar and the number of arguments expand to the last argument

Comment: @Depado Because you can only give one argument to `cd`.

Comment: @JoSo I didn't realize that the first `$` was escaped.

Comment: It's a bit of an obvious question, but **what are your trying to achieve**?

Comment: He's trying to gain understanding of the code.  Isn't that obvious as well?

Comment: @jangroth It's a shell function that creates a sequence of subdirectories, and then cd's into the last one.

Comment: @Barmar: Ok. But bizarre.

Comment: @Depado, the `cd "$@"` will fail if more than one path is given.

Comment: @jangroth `"$@"` expands to all the arguments to the function. So if you do `mkdircd foo bar baz` it will create directories `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, then `cd baz`.

Comment: @Alfe: I don't find it that obvious.

Comment: @jangroth, »but what the meaning of« [sic] is a strong indicator for that >;-)

Comment: As an aside: the function body could be simplified to the much more readable `mkdir -p "$@" && cd "$_"` - `$_` expands to the expanded last token of the previous command.

Comment: @Alfe: No it won't, `cd /foo /bar /quux` works just fine and `cd`s to `/foo`. I am too lazy to check POSIX if that is required behaviour, but my current `bash` implements it like this and just drops all additional parameters but the first and returns without error.

Comment: Okay, but the creator of that code here wanted to `cd` into the last, not the first.

Answer (score 6):

`eval` receives a *string* as argument and evaluates it as a shell command; so in normal situations what you see in the source is evaluated twice (once when building the `eval` command, then once more when `eval` is running).

This double evaluation (shell variable substitution, escaping, etc.) blows up the syntax a little, so it seems like gibberish.

```
cd "\"\$$#\""
```

evaluates to

```
cd "$4"
```

(assuming that `$#` was `4`).  And that, when `eval` is running, will evaluate to

```
cd /my/new/path
```

(assuming that `$4` was `/my/new/path`).

Why that `$#` thing?  Because your shell function will create *all* paths you pass to it, and then attempts to `cd` into the *last* given path (which is `$4` if four paths are given).

Comment: (disregard my comment, I missed the escaped $)

Comment: On my bash i tried `function tt() { eval echo \"\"$$#\"\"; }` but `$$` got evaluated before `$#` giving me the result `6148#`, which was my process id.

Comment: @RedX:  But this is not what OP gave. You missed the escape before the first dollar

Comment: `$$` is the pid, but in the OP we see `\$$#` instead.  Note the backslash which escapes the first dollar.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in `bash`, there is a safer way to access the *last* argument to the function (which is what `eval cd "\"\$$#\""` does.

```
cd "${@: -1}"
```